# Any default microphone preference setting to change voice for anonymity?

Tags: macos, microphone, voice

Is there any default microphone preference setting to change voice for anonymity?
If no what are the popular free app for Mac (Catalina)?

Answer (score 3):

A Mac can change its own voice, like when it's reading a text file, but not your voice.  One free software package that does what you want is [MorphVox Jr.](https://screamingbee.com/morphvox-mac-free-voice-changer) It can change a man's voice to a woman's and woman's to man.  There are examples on the link I sent. This version is free. The full version is $40.

[This link](https://blogs.systweak.com/best-voice-changing-app-for-mac/) lists 5 top voice changing apps. They are Voxal Voice Changer, MorphVox, Voice Candy, Voice Changer Plus, and Voice Swap. You can read about them on the link.

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1

You cannot achieve this directly through `System Preferences » Sound » Input`. If you're looking for fleⅺbility, low cost (or free), maⅺmum variation, natural sound, and the ability to carry on a real-time conversation, consider using a digital audio workstation (DAW), with a combination of:

1. [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) (free, routes audio)
2. [LineIn | SoundSource 3](https://rogueamoeba.com/legacy/): (free, combines mic and audio sources)
3. Audio production software/DAW

   - [Adobe Audition](https://www.adobe.com/ca/products/audition.html) (commercial)
   - [Apple GarageBand](https://www.apple.com/ca/mac/garageband/) (free)
   - [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/mac/) (free & open-source)
   - [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) (commercial, does not require items 1. and 2.)
4. Change voice. Some of the best effects to start with are:

   - Raise pitch
   - Stretch and pitch
   - Bend pitch
   - Distortion
   - Doppler Shift
   - Reverb
   - Modulation
   - Delay
   - Echo

## Option 2

If you do not need to carry on a realtime conversation, you could write what you have to say and have Acrobat narrate it.

Save your script as a PDF. Setup QuickTime to record audio from your computer. Depending on your set up, you may need to install Soundflower to route your audio correctly. Start recording in QuickTime. Open Adobe Acrobat and press <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> or click `View » Read Out Loud » Activate Read Out Loud`.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for combining all these tool you mentioned? I cannot adjust everything together. Thanks

Comment: Here are some of the resources that were helpful to me.

Comment: Sorry about the delay @SazzadHissainKhan, please see below.

Answer (score 2):

## Steps

1. Steps
2. Install LineIn
3. Install Soundflower
4. Steps to Record Skype Calls (and any Mac audio) in QuickTime
5. Configuration
6. Workflow(s)

> Note: If you have a Markdown text editor and previewer on your computer, you'll be able to use the local links. I'm a huge fan of Brett Terpstra's [nvALT](https://brettterpstra.com/projects/nvalt/). BTW, a new version, [nvUltra](https://nvultra.com/) is coming soon.
>
> If you are going to use a Markdown editor, remove the `<pre>` tags or copy the raw table data for them to render properly.

## Install LineIn

- [⤓ LineIn 2.3 for Mac](https://rogueamoeba.com/legacy/downloads/LineIn-230.zip)

  - LineIn 2.3 will run (officially) on MacOS 10.7 – 10.12.
  - I'm sticking with Mojave (10.14.6). It runs flawless on my box.
  - If you're running 10.6 or earlier, checkout [Legacy Software - Rogue Amoeba](https://rogueamoeba.com/legacy/)
  - LineIn a super-simple, but powerful utility
- Just follow the download instructions.

---

These are my verbatim installation notes (edited and formatted for clarity).

It's not as bad as it looks. It was much easier using this as a checklist so that I didn't step over any important steps.

The `file:///Application/app_name.app/` links will open or go to the specified software if it's installed in your Applications folder (or other respective default folder), located at the root level of your boot drive.

## Install Soundflower

Inter-application Audio Driver

**Soundflower** is a virtual audio device that provides an easy and simple way for **Max/MSP** and other applications to send and receive audio to and from any other application. Running with very low latency and cpu usage, **Soundflower** allows each client application to use its usual buffer size.

### Installing Soundflower

Run the **Soundflower Installer.pkg**. You will be asked for an administrator account password. One file, **Soundflower.kext**, will be installed in the Extensions Folder. The remainder of the supporting files will be installed to `/Applications/Soundflower`.

If you experience difficulty installing Soundflower, it is recommended that you run the Uninstall Soundflower applescript that is provided on the disk image.

### Using Soundflower

**Soundflower** presents itself as one of two coreaudio devices. In most cases, you will want to use the 2-channel device. To send the output of one application to another, simply select **Soundflower** as the output device within the first application and **Soundflower** as the input device within the second application.

If an application does not allow you to specify audio devices, you can make **Soundflower** the default input or output device inside the Sound panel in the System Preferences, or with the Audio MIDI Setup utility application.

The 16-channel device is provided for more complex routing situations, and can be used with more than two applications simultaneously if the applications support audio routing to any channel, as Max/MSP does.

Note that **Soundflower**'s audio channels represent a global audio space. If more than one application is sending its output to the same channel, the audio will be mixed. If you want an application to send and receive audio through **Soundflower**, (for instance using **Max/MSP** to manipulate and return another application's audio) you must send and receive the audio on different audio channels or a feedback loop will be created.

Example To send audio from **iTunes** to **Max/MSP**, open the System Preferences and select **Soundflower (2ch)** as the device for sound output inside the **Sound** panel. Then, inside** Max/MSP's DSP Status Window**, select **Core Soundflower (2ch)** as the input device. All output of iTunes should now be sent to **Max/MSP's adc~** object.

### Troubleshooting

If you are hearing clicks or breakups, try increasing the buffer size of both applications (set within each application).

### Removing Soundflower

From an account with administrator privileges, double-click on the **Uninstall Soundflower.scpt** file. This will run an AppleScript, in which you will be asked for your password.

History The Soundflower Change Log is maintained online at: https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original/wiki &/or https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original/wiki/Change-Log A more detailed history can be found at: https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original/commits/master

---

## Steps to Record Skype Calls (and any Mac audio) in QuickTime

1. In Skype - start playing audio (test via `Echo123`)
2. In QuickTime - Type `⌃⌥⌘N` for New Audio Recording - In the popup menu next to record button select **`Soundflower (2ch)`** as the input - Hit record!

## Configuration

1. Open Audio MIDI Setup
2. Hit the `+` button in the bottom left corner and select `Create Multi Output Device`
3. In the panel that appears on the right, select `USB Audio Device` **AND** `Soundflower (2ch)`
4. Then hit the `⚙️` dropdown and select `use this device for sound output`

---

References

---

1. [mattingalls/Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower)
2. [Signed Version for macOS Mojave (10.15) and earlier](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/tag/2.0b2)
3. [Soundflower | Rogue Amoeba](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/)
4. [RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original](https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original)
5. <file:///System/Library/Extensions/NVSMU.kext>
6. file:///Library/Extensions/Soundflower.kext/
7. [Broadcast All Audio from Your Mac Computer](https://help.radio.co/live-broadcasting/general-live-broadcasting-information/broadcast-all-audio-from-your-mac-computer)
8. [7 Useful OS X Shortcuts for Audio Engineers](https://theproaudiofiles.com/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcuts/)

---

## Workflow(s)

### Google Hangouts Workflow & Configuration

```
| Step | App                      | Input             | Output              | Ch Vol, etc.                                              |
|:----:|:-------------------------|:------------------|:--------------------|:----------------------------------------------------------|
|  1.  | [**Sound**][1]           | [3x Mic Input][2] | [Record Mac][2]     | `⌥+fn+F10-12` opens [**Sound**][1]                        |
|  2.  | [**LineIn**][3]          | [3x Mic Input][1] | Soundflower (2ch)   | Click **`Play Thru`**                                     |
|  3.  | [**Google Hangouts**][4] | Soundflower (2ch) | [Default device][1] | 10                                                        |
|  4.  | [**QuickTime**][5]       | Soundflower (2ch) | [Default device][1] | `⌘+I` (show inspector)<br />`⌃+⌥+⌘+N` New Audio Recording |
|  5.  | [![][5i]][5]             |                   |                     |                                                           |
```

### Skype Workflow & Configuration

```
| Step | App                | Input             | Output              | Ch Vol, etc.                                              |
|:----:|:-------------------|:------------------|:--------------------|:----------------------------------------------------------|
|  1.  | [**Sound**][1]     | [3x Mic Input][2] | [Record Skype][2]   | `⌥+fn+F10-12` opens [**Sound**][1]                        |
|  2.  | [**LineIn**][3]    | [3x Mic Input][1] | Soundflower (2ch)   | Click **`Play Thru`**                                     |
|  3.  | [**Skype**][4]     | Soundflower (2ch) | [Default device][1] | 10                                                        |
|  4.  | [**QuickTime**][5] | Soundflower (2ch) | [Default device][1] | `⌘+I` (show inspector)<br />`⌃+⌥+⌘+N` New Audio Recording |
|  5.  | [![][5i]][5]       |                   |                     |                                                           |
```

Workflow & Configuration Template

```
| Step | App                                     | Input             | Output              | Ch Vol, etc.          |
|:----:|:----------------------------------------|:------------------|:--------------------|:----------------------|
|  1.  | [**Sound**][1]                          | [3x Mic Input][2] | [Record Skype][2]   | n/a                   |
|  2.  | [**LineIn**][3]                         | [3x Mic Input][1] | Soundflower (2ch)   | Click **`Play Thru`** |
|  3.  | [**Skype**][4]/["audio app"][8]         | Soundflower (2ch) | [Default device][1] | 10                    |
|  4.  | [**QuickTime**][5]/["recording app"][9] | Soundflower (2ch) | [Default device][1] | `⌘I` (show inspector) |
|  5.  | Optional ⬎                              |                   |                     |                       |
|  6.  | [Audio MIDI Setup][2]                   | `3x Mic Input`    | `Record Skype`      |                       |
|  7.  | Other apps???⬎                          |                   |                     |                       |
|  8.  | [Chrome (YouTube, etc.)][7]             |                   |                     |                       |
```

Tips:

1. Micro Volume Adjustments

   - ↓ ⟶ `⇧+⌥+fn+F11`
   - ↑ ⟶ `⇧+⌥+fn+F12`
2. Silent Volume Adjustments `⇧+fn+F11` or `⇧+fn+F11`. Holding `Shift` doesn't work for micro adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the resources that were helpful to me.

If you're going to go the LineIn/Sunflower method, this will help you configure your setup. [Broadcast All Audio from Your Mac Computer](https://help.radio.co/en/articles/899792-broadcast-all-audio-from-your-mac-computer).

It shows you how to broadcast all of your computer's audio, like input devices and media players, to an online radio station. Stop at the point where you can use LineIn to route your audio to your preferred device.

From here, you can process your voice through your digital audio workstation (DAW).

> Experiment with your DAW's effects or plug-ins until you get voice changes that you like.

If you're going with [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/), [Recording from Skype. etc.](https://rogueamoeba.com/support/knowledgebase/?showArticle=VoIPRecording), and [Record a Skype Call With Audio Hijack](https://www.lemonproductions.ca/how-to-record-a-skype-call-with-audio-hijack/) walk you through routing your audio correctly.

Once you've got your audio routing setup, then you can add and configure
Audio Hijack's `Built-In Effects`.

I'll follow this message with my setup and configuration notes.

Answer (score 0):

[Voxal voice changer](https://www.nchsoftware.com/voicechanger/index.html) is so far the best with more customizable options for non commercial usage.